# Как отправить HTTP запрос с помощью OkHttp?

Tags: android, http

Вылетает приложения при старте.

**Создал класс Get:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class Get {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String run(String url) throws IOException {
        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
}
```

**В MainActivity вызываю его так:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Get test = new Get();

        try {
            String te123 = test.run("https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=E52.091002%S23.721111");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**В AndroidManifest указал:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Что не так делаю?

Comment: Лог ошибки можно предоставить?

Comment: лучше сразу использовать retrofit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

метод execute() выполнятся синхронно, то есть, в вашем случае в main thread, вот android и ругается.
Нужно вызывать асинхронно

```
 public void run(String url, Callback callback) {

        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }
```

а в активити

```
Get test = new Get();

    test.run("https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=E52.091002%S23.721111",
            new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            //todo work with response, parse and etc...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Ты выполняешь запрос синхронно его нужно вынести в отдельный поток например вот так

```
public class Get {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void run(final String url, final ResponseCallBack callback) throws IOException {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                final String sResponse = response.body().string();

                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        callback.onResponse(sResponse);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

public interface ResponseCallBack {
    void onResponse(String response);
}

И в активити можно вызывать так

Get test = new Get();

    try {
        test.run("https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=E52.091002%S23.721111", new ResponseCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("onResponse", response);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Здравствуйте!  
Сорри, в Java я новичёк  
Можете помочь со следующими вопросами?  
---  
1) Правильно я понял, что класс Get нужно создать внутри класса активити?  
2) Андроид-студио у меня ругается "unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown Response response = client.newCall(request).execute(); ... "  
как понимаю, методы .execute и .string   
нужно заключить в try/catch ?  
3) и... мой код не попадает никак в место где у вас Log.e  
запрос реально проходит  
в переменной sResponse контент есть